KMP: IC internal error: can not find main library for test
We have Kotlin KMP library that targets Android, iOS and Browser platforms. After Updating Android Studio to Ladybug 2024.2.1 and Gradle to 8.9, we can no longer build for Browser because common:compileTestDevelopmentExecutableKotlinJs task errors out with the following error:
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IC internal error: can not find main library for test
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.ic.ICUtilsKt.icError-5T69zGA(ICUtils.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.ic.ICUtilsKt.notFoundIcError-5T69zGA(ICUtils.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.ic.ICUtilsKt.notFoundIcError-5T69zGA$default(ICUtils.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.ic.CacheUpdater$CacheUpdaterInternal.<init>(CacheUpdater.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.ic.CacheUpdater.loadIrForDirtyFilesAndInitCompiler(CacheUpdater.kt:663)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.ic.CacheUpdater.loadIrAndMakeIrFragmentGenerators(CacheUpdater.kt:744)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.ic.CacheUpdater.actualizeCaches(CacheUpdater.kt:768)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JsIrCompiler.prepareIcCaches(K2JsIrCompiler.kt:615)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JsIrCompiler.doExecute(K2JsIrCompiler.kt:253)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JSCompiler.doExecute(K2JSCompiler.java:181)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JSCompiler.doExecute(K2JSCompiler.java:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1523)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

common is the only module in which this task errors out. In other modules it doesn't error out.
Previously we were using Gradle 7.6.
